# JTA, Hibernate with atomikos Multiple XA Datasources not maintaing transaction in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, atomikos

I have 2 `MySQL` schema and respective `MysqlXADataSource` configured as below -

```
@Bean(name = "sourceDataSource")
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    MysqlXADataSource dataSource = new MysqlXADataSource();
    dataSource.setPinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection(true);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUser(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

    AtomikosDataSourceBean atomikosDataSourceBean = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
atomikosDataSourceBean.setUniqueResourceName("SourceDB");
    atomikosDataSourceBean.setXaDataSource(dataSource);

    /*DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);*/
    System.out.println("Creatign Source data source.");
    return atomikosDataSourceBean;
}

@Bean(name = "sourceSessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(@Qualifier("jtaTransactionManager") JtaTransactionManager jts) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class", "jta");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform");

    //hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", AtomikosJtaPlatform.class.getName());
    sessionFactoryBean.setJtaTransactionManager(jts);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    System.out.println("Creatign Source Session Factory.");
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

And

```
@Bean(name="destinationDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    MysqlXADataSource dataSource = new MysqlXADataSource();
    dataSource.setPinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection(true);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUser(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

    AtomikosDataSourceBean atomikosDataSourceBean = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
atomikosDataSourceBean.setUniqueResourceName("DestinationDB");
    atomikosDataSourceBean.setXaDataSource(dataSource);

    /*DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

    System.out.println("Creatign Destination Data Source.");*/
    return atomikosDataSourceBean;
}

@Bean(name="destinationSessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(@Qualifier("jtaTransactionManager") JtaTransactionManager jts) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class", "jta");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform");
    sessionFactoryBean.setJtaTransactionManager(jts);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    System.out.println("Creatign Destination Session Factoy.");
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

Transaction Configuration

```
@Bean("transactionManager")
public UserTransactionManager transactionManager(){
    UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
    return userTransactionManager;
}

@Bean("userTransaction")
public UserTransaction userTransaction(){
    J2eeUserTransaction userTransaction = new J2eeUserTransaction();
    return userTransaction;
}

@Bean("jtaTransactionManager")
public JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager(@Qualifier("transactionManager") UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager, @Qualifier("userTransaction") UserTransaction userTransaction) {
    JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setTransactionManager(userTransactionManager);
    transactionManager.setUserTransaction(userTransaction);
    //transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    System.out.println("Creatign JTA Transaction Manager.");
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Service ...

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "jtaTransactionManager", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=Exception.class, timeout=500000)
public void transform() throws JobExecutionException{
    System.out.println("START == Starting Trandformation ... ");

    //Clean Up
    transformProduct.cleanUp();
    transformService.cleanUp();
    transformResources.cleanUp();

    transformResources.transform();
    transformService.transform();
    transformProduct.transform();
    LOG.info("END == Starting Transformation ... ");
    throw new JobExecutionException();
}
```

And there are respective sub service classes `transformProduct`, `transformService` & `transformResources` and these classes are using the `sessionFactory` implemented dao classes. I have no where mentioned commit or rollback. everything should be transnational. but somehow its not working

Comment: What isn't working? Also why not simply use the out-of-the-box support for Atomikos? You are throwing a checked exception, rollback only happens for `RuntimeException` s. Your `jtaTransactionManager` should be named `transactionManager` as that is the default name expected by Spring. If that doesn't match you need to explicitly tell `@EnableTransactionManagement` which transaction manager to use.

Comment: I think wrong transactionManager is used. By default `@Transactional` got your UserTransactionManager bean

Comment: @M.Deinum @StanislavL I have changed couple of things `Datasources returning atomikosDataSourceBean and added unique name for them.` and i think that was the issue. Now transaction are getting rolled back but need to verify. Will post in case of any issue.

Comment: added `@Transactional(transactionManager = "jtaTransactionManager" ...)`

Comment: @M.Deinum, as mentioned in the my comments.. adding these extra code has resolved the issue. Thanks for help and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. There was mistake in the code -

1. XA Datasource must be wrapped with `AtomikosDataSourceBean` ans should return `AtomikosDataSourceBean` reference.
2. Assign unique name to `AtomikosDataSourceBean`.
3. Service Method should be made `@Transactional(transactionManager = "jtaTransactionManager" ...)`, provide Spring `JtaTransactionManager`.
4. `JtaTransactionManager` should be referenced with `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` having `com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction` implementation.
5. `JtaTransactionManager` should be referenced with `com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager` implementation.
6. Rest of the Code is correct in the question.

This is straight forward out-of-the-box support for Atomikos.